# Should searching be done in the view?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Should searching be done explicitly in the view, or done in the controller and results passed to the view?

My guess is the view, to keep controllers skinny. If so, should the controller pass the search parameters to the view, or can the view get those themselves through $_POST, $_GET variables? My take on it is that the controller is responsible for delegation (routing) and handling requests, so I would think that it should pass the view whatever data it needs to do its job (same for the model). Is this correct?

Thanks

Comment: In my own project the controllers handles the request and calls a function in the model which returns the data to to controller which add all the needed info to a view variable. I think the view should only contain stuff to display and not (lots of) programming logic

Comment: I thought in MVC, the view has the right to contact the Model, (only) when it needs to display data?

Comment: it depends. It is ok to call some model's functions from within a view. Although some stuff can easily be 'pre-parsed' / 'perpared' in the controller. I think in the end it's all a matter of taste.

Comment: /offtopic @BDuelz: why can't I type your name with an @ in front of it in my comment?

Comment: nevermind: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98922/cannot-use-name-in-my-comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right that the controllers should be kept skinny, but the corollary to that is to have [fat models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568553/mvc-in-php-fat-model-or-fat-controller); here, you should pass the search parameters to your model.

The controller can deal with the `$_REQUEST` parameters but should translate them into something generic for the model class to deal with. It can then return you a collection of models which match the search parameters, and your controller can set that collection onto the view.

Comment: So the view class does nothing but display what it's given? Can it not have contact with the model directly?

Comment: The view should be responsible for choosing how to display the model; for instance, if the intended output is XML then the view could call a `toXml()` method on the model; another view may choose to represent the model in a different way. Again, this lends itself to more logic in the model.

Comment: But wouldn't a toXml method require putting presentation logic in the model? Why not just create a new view that would prepare that data to be shown in an xml file?

Comment: If this was a one-off view, then yes I guess that would be pretty redundant, and it might be better for the controller to pass the model (or some primitive representation of it) for the view to do its work. My example works better for when the view is shared, like for instance one which knows how to render objects with a certain interface.